# How to ask about folder size

Tags: phrase-request, sentence-choice, informal-language, email, sentence-request

In an email message, which would be better to say:

> How much is the folder size?

or:

> What is the folder size?

Comment: @userr2684291 - While I appreciate the irony, I think this "discrepancy" may provide a clue about intent. Perhaps the O.P. wants the to write the email using conversational English, and wants to know which of the two options sounds more natural.

Comment: @J.R. Haha, yeah. I was in the middle of checking their post history but I got sidetracked. Linda: I'll edit the tags, and you can revert the edit if you find it at variance with your original intent.

Answer (score 3):

*How much?* asks for a quantity, and suggests you're asking the price of the folder. Ordinarily we say

> What size is the folder?  *if we are asking for a 'stock' size (e.g., 'letter' or 'legal'), or*
>   How big is the folder? *if we are asking for dimensions*.

These are usual with most 'primary' qualities, such as size, color, height, length, weight and the like.

> What color is your umbrella?
>   How tall is Bob?
>   What length plank *or* How long a plank do you need?
>   What weight does he box at?  *or* How heavy is he?

Comment: What if the folder they're talking about is a directory in a file system; e.g., on a hard drive?

Comment: @userr2684291 "How big is the folder?" -- assuming that you're asking for a measurement of its contents, so many mb, which we think of as a 'volume' not a 'quantity'.

Comment: I've been practicing 'What is the size of the folder?' Any difference? Pronoun + auxiliary? or Pronoun + adjective?

Comment: @MaulikV - Your option sounds fine to me.